# What is the function of the voltage meter in this circuit?

Tags: resistors, voltage-measurement

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMGont.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

See the above schematic. I don't know if it's 100% correct, because it's my first time using it and some of the symbols are quite different to what I'm used to, but I think it's correct. So basically, my book says that the voltage meter in this circuit measures 0 V in this case. I honestly don't know why this is the case, and I don't intuitively grok the use of the voltage meter in this circuit. What exactly is it measuring, and why is 0 V in this case?

Answer (score 4):

The circuit is a [Wheatstone bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) that is in balance. The voltmeter will read a positive or negative voltage if any of the four resistors changes slightly. The voltage change is proportional to the excitation (the 5V source).

This is a standard building-block that you will encounter in many measurement circuits.

Answer (score 1):

The volt meter isn't measuring anything particularly useful in this circuit. I'm assuming it's just there for the sake of the book example.

The meter reads 0V because it reads the voltage difference between two points. Each of those points is at the same voltage, so it reads 0. To understand why each of those points is the same voltage, and what the voltage is, you should study Ohm's law. Each of those points is at the center of a voltage divider. Further, each voltage divider is in parallel with a supply of 5V.